# How do i get the index of a string in an array and assign the string after that indexed string to a variable?

Tags: bash

I am trying to make a bash script that allows the user to input the command line arguments in any order, but no specific order: For example script.sh -F File_name.sh -FN folder_name or be able to run the script as script.sh -FN folder_name -F File_name.sh and vice versa.

I've tried many different solutions in assigning the index of a string to a variable but it wont let me only get the index of string and then increment it by one to get the File_name, i keep getting issues:

```
command_I_ran = "script_name.sh -F cheese"
args=("$@")

for i in "${args[@]}"; do
    if [ "$i" == "-F" ] ; then
        a=(( ${args[$i]}++ ))
        echo "$a"
        
    fi
done
```

it returns "-F" but i want to assign "cheese" to a variable

Comment: `man bash` and search for `getopts`. Good luck.

Comment: `${args[$i]}` is a string, not a number, so `++` makes little sense

Comment: How do I turn it into a number; increment by one (it’s index) then use that new number to get my argument I know it would be ${args[new_number]} for the new index but how do I get the index of the string $I and add one to the number

Answer (score 1):

As already been suggested, read more about `getopts`. Quick sample:

```
while getopts ":f:d:" OPTION; do
    case $OPTION in
    f) file=$OPTARG;;
    d) directory=$OPTARG;;
    esac
done
printf "File = %s\nDirectory = %s\n" "$file" "$directory"
```

Execution result:

```
$ bash script.sh -d somedir -f somefile
File = somefile
Directory = somedir

$ bash script.sh -f somefile -d somedir 
File = somefile
Directory = somedir
```

Answer (score 1):

It is often helpful to forego processing the positional parameters in an array and simply step through them as normal with `shift`. This also makes your code usable on POSIX shells as well as bash.

In your case you simply want to check whether the `-F` option has been given as a positional parameter, and if it has assign the following parameter to some variable `myvar` below. (you should also do rudimentary tests to ensure what follows after `-F` is in a form you want to accept)

The approach is simple, you loop `while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do ... shift; done` to loop through each parameter. Using a `case ... esac` statement makes it easy to test for option arguments your script accepts. When a valid option is found, simply `shift` again to move the next positional parameter into `$1` and assign it to your variable.

A short manual example could be:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do            # loop over each positional parameter
  case "$1" in
    -F )                          # handle the -F option
      shift                       # shift to next positional parameter
      [ "${1:0:1}" = "-" ] && {   # validate it doesn't begin with '-'
        printf "error: invalid option following -F: '%s'\n" "$1" >&2
        exit 1
      }
      myvar=$1    # assign parameter that follows to your variable
      ;;
    * )   # handle any options not handled as a valid case above
      printf "unhandled argument: '%s'\n" "$1" >&2
      ;;
  esac
  shift   # shift to next parameter
done

# validate myvar is set or exit
[ -z "$myvar" ] && { echo "myvar unset" >&2; exit 1; }

# output myvar
echo "myvar: $myvar"
```

(**note:** the do it yourself approach is an alternative you can use instead of using the `getopts` builtin -- which isn't without it's pitfalls either -- but `getopts` is certainly more robust than what you will just whip up on the fly for complex options and arguments)

**Example Use/Output**

The well-formed argument case:

```
$ bash shiftcliargs.sh -F cheese
myvar: cheese
```

The case where two option arguments are strung together:

```
$ bash shiftcliargs.sh -F -n
error: invalid option following -F: '-n'
```

Or no option following `-F` or no arguments at all:

```
$ bash shiftcliargs.sh -F
myvar unset
```

(result is the same for no arguments provided)

Invalid argument case:

```
$ bash shiftcliargs.sh -P
unhandled argument: '-P'
myvar unset
```

So with relatively few lines of bash (or shell), you can implement a simple option input scheme. Again, it will not be as robust as what you can do with the builtin `getopts`, but for simple cases, it is an alternative that is portable.

Comment: You are a saint!